# How to mount an existing Azure fileshare to a Pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-storage-files, azure-files

Can someone please let me know what are the steps that needs to be followed to mount an Azure fileshare that has files in it, and will need to mount it on a pod in Kubernetes.

Comment: The follwoing document details dynamic provisioning of an Azure file share as a Kubernetes persistent volume in an AKS cluster.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv

Answer (score 1):

As I see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux), Azure using SMB protocol for access a data:

> Azure Files can be mounted either via SMB 2.1 and SMB 3.0. For connections coming from clients on-premises or in other Azure regions, Azure Files will reject SMB 2.1 (or SMB 3.0 without encryption). If secure transfer required is enabled for a storage account, Azure Files will only allow connections using SMB 3.0 with encryption.

Kubernetes do not support SMB directly, but has support of special type of volumes - `AzureFile`, which will provide a SMB configuration automatically for you.

Next, for mount a storage, you need [to](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/azure_file/README.md):

1. Install packages to your nodes: `yum -y install cifs-utils`. If you using Debian-like distribs like Ubuntu, check how to install that packages in your OS (probably, they have same names).
2. No, you need to:

   > Obtain an Microsoft Azure storage account and create a secret that contains the base64 encoded Azure Storage account name and key. In the secret file, base64-encode Azure Storage account name and pair it with name azurestorageaccountname, and base64-encode Azure Storage access key and pair it with name azurestorageaccountkey.

   After that, you can create a Kubernetes secret with that file:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azure-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: azhzdGVzdA==
  azurestorageaccountkey: eElGMXpKYm5ub2pGTE1Ta0JwNTBteDAyckhzTUsyc2pVN21GdDRMMTNob0I3ZHJBYUo4akQ2K0E0NDNqSm9nVjd5MkZVT2hRQ1dQbU02WWFOSHk3cWc9PQ==`

3. Now you can mount a share into your pod:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: azure
spec:
 containers:
  - image: kubernetes/pause
    name: azure
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
 volumes:
      - name: azure
        azureFile:
          secretName: azure-secret
          shareName: k8stest
          readOnly: false`

Comment: I get the following issue:
" MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azure" : mount failed: exit status 1 Mounting command: mount Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o username=devops3 ,password=xxxxxxxxxxx== ,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,vers=3.0 //devops3 .file.core.windows.net/k8stest /var/lib/kubelet/pods/06a060d1-4fr2-11e8-b530-000d3a11ee2f/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/azure Output: mount error: could not resolve address for devops3 .file.core.windows.net: Unknown error "
It looks like a space is added in the host-address. Can you please check and confirm from your end ?

Comment: It is a bit hard to say based on that paste, but yes, looks like there is a space between `devops3` and `.file.core.windows.net`. Try to check your config, maybe there is a space in `shareName`.

Comment: The ` shareName ` as understand is the name of the fileshare and is  not related to the url which has the reference to the storage account name/ username =  devops3

Comment: The issue caused by the space was due to an encoding issue , which has been resolved. But after successful mounting the fileshare as per the logs, I was not able to see a folder /mnt/azure created on the pod/container. Can you please show how we can confirm from within the pod/contaner ?

Comment: You can check `Volumes:` block in the output of `kubectl describe $POD` command. It should be there.

Comment: I see the volume block as as ` Volumes:
  azure:
    Type:        AzureFile (an Azure File Service mount on the host and bind mount to the pod)
    SecretName:  azure-secret
    ShareName:   k8stest
    ReadOnly:    false
  default-token-254v5:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-254v5
    Optional:    false
  `
Here my intention is to do an exec to the pod and container and access the files in the Fileshare, which I am not able to as I am not able to find the directory mentioned in the yaml file.

Comment: Your AzureFile path mounted on node and bind mount to the pod. First, check that share on a node where container running, second - check `Mounts:` in `describe` of the pod to get a path in the container.

Comment: Yes, I see it as follows:
`     Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-254v5 (ro)  `

I am able to find this mount on the node, but it does not have the files in the fileshare.

Comment: That is only a service account. Looks like your volume not mounted into the pod. Please check `volumeMounts` path in your yaml. That is an only way how I can help you. If configs is correct - it should work. Moreover, it already mounted on node, so you just need to bind it into your container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168099/discussion-between-ajov-crowe-and-anton-kostenko).

Comment: Hi there , I'm facing the same decoding issue with the space. Can you please share how you resolved it ?